# How to draw slices inside a circle without radio as center

Tags: android, kotlin, canvas, geometry, slice

I need to draw a circle and fill it according to a percentage value as image shows.
[image: expected result]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wcp6s.png)

I have tried to draw it using canvas:

```
@SuppressLint("DrawAllocation")
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
    super.onDraw(canvas)
    rectF = RectF(0f + margin, 0f + margin, width.toFloat() - margin, height.toFloat() - margin)
    val scaledValues = scale()
    var sliceStartPoint = 0F
    for (i in scaledValues.indices) {
        slicePaint.color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, sliceColors[i])
        canvas!!.drawArc(rectF!!, sliceStartPoint, scaledValues[i], true, slicePaint)
        canvas.drawArc(rectF!!, sliceStartPoint, scaledValues[i], true, centerPaint)
        sliceStartPoint += scaledValues[i]
    }
}
```

The problem is that I got all lines centered to radio (as a Pie) instead of slices.

[image: current result]

I tried to set `usecenter:false` but it was not successful result.
Any idea how to draw an arc without set the center point as vertice?

Comment: You can make needed segments creating paths from arc and lines. Also consider drawing full circle but with clipping rectangle.

Comment: Thank you @MBo. I am searching how to create segments and paths from arc and lines. I will share the answer when I get it

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need rotate the canvas & a little math.

```
private val slicePaint = Paint()
    private val centerPaint = Paint().apply {
        color = 0x33333333
    }
    private val sliceColors = arrayListOf<Int>(Color.GRAY, Color.RED, Color.BLACK)
    private var rectF: RectF? = null
    private val margin = 0f
    private var rotDeg = -120f

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        rectF = RectF(0f + margin, 0f + margin, width.toFloat() - margin, height.toFloat() - margin)
        canvas.save()
        canvas.rotate(rotDeg, canvas.width /2.0f, canvas.height/2.0f)
//        val scaledValues = scale()
//        var sliceStartPoint = 0F
        for (i in percent.indices) {
            slicePaint.color = sliceColors[i]  // ContextCompat.getColor(context, sliceColors[i])
            var d = percent2degree(percent[i])
            canvas!!.drawArc(rectF!!, d, -2 * d, false, slicePaint)
//            canvas.drawArc(rectF!!, sliceStartPoint, scaledValues[i], true, centerPaint)
//            sliceStartPoint += scaledValues[i]
        }
        canvas.restore()
    }

    private fun percent2degree(p:Float): Float {
        return (acos((0.5 - p)/ 0.5) / Math.PI * 180).toFloat()
    }
var percent = arrayOf(1.0f, 0.9f, 0.55f)  // 0.5 + 0.3 + 0.2 = 100%
```

[image: result]
[image: Whole Code]

Comment: Thanks for your response, @yw07. I have tried your solution but I get just a circle filled with two colors plus white. Also the two colors just fill until the half of the circle. The rest of the circle is filled with white color.
I have set percent with (0.5f ,0.1f, 0.4f)
Could you tell me what I am doing wrong, please?

Comment: I've forgotten the percent part and reEdit the code. Here's some explanation: 1. you draw the gray part first, then draw the red arc over the gray, then draw the black over the red. Btw, I think there're many ways to draw without arc. you can draw three colored lines and draw circle clip the lines then do a rotation.